# Wordpress Admin Welcome Message

Tags: wordpress, customization, panel, admin

I am trying to create my own "panel" on the first page in the Wordpress admin area. When you first login you will get to a page which shows different panels like the one saying "welcome ..". I would like to create my own panel (or customize the welcome panel) so that my client will get a special message from me every time he logs in to the admin page.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is an up to date plugin in the repo which does exactly that so I'd recommend having a look at the code to see how they have gone about tackling it.  You can then strip out whatever you need and implement it as your own plugin or in your theme.

[Wordpress custom messages plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-welcome-messages/)

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin [AG Custom Admin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ag-custom-admin)

that can be used for creating custom HTML content on Dashboard page.